# How to enable proxy caching on Apache / Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, cache

I have already enabled browser caching on my apache but there's another thing, audit report of chrome for my web page suggests "Leverage proxy caching (35)". Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You only want to allow public proxies to do caching on resources that are public (accessible to the world, no authentication, etc) and static (the same content is delivered to all users). So you may want to limit this to just content where it makes sense, like JS, CSS, and image files.

That said, what you'll want to do is to set the `Cache-Control` header.  Something like this, to allow a public proxy to keep the content an hour:

```
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600, public"
```

The `Vary: Accept-Encoding` is also important to make sure the public proxies don't break when your content is compressed, but `mod_deflate` should handle this for you if needed.

Comment: where should i set this header?

Comment: @GaganDeep If it's appropriate for everything in your server to be cached, then put it in your `<VirtualHost>` block.  Otherwise, put it somewhere that applies only to resources that should be cached, something like `<Location /static/>` or `<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg)$">`

Comment: Can this go in `.htaccess`?